# How do I manage sessions on clients and servers that use react and spring boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, session

I'm working on a spring boot and a react
An error occurred in the login implementation status.

It's a test project, so I'm trying to implement and maintain logins using only sessions.
Logic configured a code that the client received the session ID sent from the server to the client, stored it in session storage, and then made a GET request to the server to retrieve the email of the ID stored in the session ID.

But is it correct that the session ID sent by the server is different from the session ID that the client sends again?

For example, if adfadsfadsfadsf is the session ID and sent it to the client, should the client send it back to the server and the server print out the session ID, the same session ID should appear like this?

```
@GetMapping("/giveMeEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUserEmail(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        // Gets the information stored in the session
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        User loggedInUser = (User) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
        
        if (loggedInUser != null) {
            String userId = loggedInUser.getUserId();
            String userEmail = loggedInUser.getEmail();
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Email: " + userEmail + ", User ID: " + userId);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Login Fail...");
        }
    }
```

```
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionId")
          axios
            .get(`${url}/api/giveMeEmail`, {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionId}`,
              },
            })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
        }}
      >
```

I want to save it to the session storage of the client through the session id generated by the server and output the user's email stored on the server through the get request